Firebase ID Token in Flutter Results in 401 Unauthorized for Cloud Function, but Works with gcloud Identity Token
I'm trying to call a Google Cloud Function from my Flutter app using a Firebase-authenticated user's ID token. Here's what I'm doing in my Flutter code:
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if (user != null) {
  String? idToken = await user.getIdToken();
  print("Id - ${idToken}");

  try {
    // Build your request URL
    String baseURL = "${ConstantValue.googlePlaceAPI}?input=pune&sessionToken=423432&apiKey=${ConstantValue.googleAPiKey}";

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${idToken}',  // Adding Firebase ID token
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };

    // Make the request
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(baseURL),
      headers: headers,
    );

    // Check and print the response
    var data = response.body.toString();
    print("$data this data from api");
    print("Status code: ${response.statusCode}");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Data fetched successfully");
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Data');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error in fetch location name: ${e.toString()}");
  }
} else {
  print("User is not authenticated");
}

Problem:

When I try to hit the API with the Firebase ID token from my Flutter app, I get the following error:
ClientException: Failed to parse header value


When I use Postman with the Firebase ID token, I get:
401 Unauthorized
Your client does not have permission to the requested URL

When I use a dummy testing token generated via gcloud auth print-identity-token, it works fine.


What I’ve Tried:

I’ve verified that the Firebase ID token is being generated correctly in my Flutter app, and it's being passed in the Authorization header as Bearer {idToken}.

The Cloud Function is set up with Firebase Admin SDK to verify the token.

I’ve checked the permissions and granted allAuthenticatedUsers the Cloud Functions Invoker role, but it still gives the 401 Unauthorized error.

I have giving function permission but getting different aud  gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding getGooglePlaceName --region="us-central1" --member="allAuthenticatedUsers"  --role="roles/run.invoker"


Questions:

Why does the Firebase ID token result in a 401 Unauthorized when making a request to the Cloud Function, even though it works with the gcloud identity token?

How can I resolve the ClientException: Failed to parse header value in Flutter?


Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Identity Tokens sent to Cloud Functions / Cloud Run require an audience value with one exception (see below). The audience value is the URL of the compute service your code is calling. The audience is part of the Identity Token verification performed by the Cloud Function Frontend. The CLI gcloud is using a Google Client ID that generates a special Identity Token.

@JohnHanley
from  gcloud auth print-identity-token
"aud": "32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com",
and
from firebase login user idToken
"aud": "",

That is why the token fails. The audience is incorrect and the token is rejected. When you create the Identity Token, specify the correct audience. I don't code in your language or platform, but there are examples with other SDKs to help point you in the right direction.

Note: do not use the same gcloud audience value when you create a token as you are not using Google's private key to sign. You must specify the URL of the service you are calling.
